# Should a UITableViewController's UITableViewCells have strong or weak pointers to its properties?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an object `myObject` in my UITableViewController set as one of its properties which I pass along to a custom UITableViewCell. I "pass it along" by then in turn setting it as a property on the cell. My question is, should this property on the UITableViewCell be weak or strong in iOS 5 using ARC?

I am confused because `myObject` is owned by the UITableViewController, which owns the UITableViewCell, which in turn has a reference to `myObject`. But there will never be a case where my UITableViewCell is alive without my UITableViewController being alive (which keeps `myObject` alive), so is there a need to have a strong pointer from the cell to the object?

I'm just slightly worried about circular references but there shouldn't be one should there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably only your controller should own the object strongly but your cell can retain it, too. It's not a bug.

Your strong references will be a tree, not a circle.